# How to add css media query in .angular-cli.json angular 5

Tags: css, angular-cli

I have requirement, that depends on device size (desktop or tablet) wants to load the different styles sheets.

In my angular project with CLI configuration I have added styles following way.

```
 "styles": [
    "dashboard-control/dashboard-panel.css",
    "dashboard-control/dashboard-changes.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

I can add the my styles in assests folder and give reference in index.html. using media I can load different styles.

But how can I use  media='screen and (max-width: 1366px)'  in .angular-cli.json

Regards
Naresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you'd like to do is not possible in the .Angular-cli.json file.
Best way to apply different styles to your dashboard are mediaqueries inside .css files.